# unable to install mysql

Tags: mysql, centos

I have CentOS isntalled in one of my server (5.6 32 Bit). I installed webmin over it and virtualmin. Unfortunately webmin was not able to install mysql for me. When I try installing it through command line using `yum install mysql`, I am getting the follwing error:

> Transaction Check Error:   file /etc/my.cnf from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1250.xml from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/cp1251.xml from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/czech/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/danish/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/dutch/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/english/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/estonian/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/french/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/german/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/greek/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/hungarian/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/italian/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/japanese/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/korean/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian-ny/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/norwegian/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/polish/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/portuguese/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/romanian/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/russian/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/serbian/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/slovak/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/spanish/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/swedish/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/share/mysql/ukrainian/errmsg.sys from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysql55-libs-5.5.28-2.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.15.0.0 from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysqlclient15-5.0.92-3.ius.el5.i386
>
> file /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.15.0.0 from install of
>   mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386 conflicts with file from package
>   mysqlclient15-5.0.92-3.ius.el5.i386
>
> Error Summary

Please help...

Comment: The error messages seem pretty self explanatory to me. You can't have both packages installed on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed something from the IUS repo, which brought in an incompatible version of MySQL libraries. That repository is well known to distribute incompatible libraries that break dependencies in this manner, and I recommend against using it.

To recover from this, you will need to:

- Identify the packages that you installed from IUS
- Find an alternate source for those packages, and install them from that source.
- Remove the IUS repo and any remaining packages

Optionally, use a different (and dependency compatible) repository for MySQL, such as the remi repository, if you need a later version of MySQL than is provided by CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are going to have to UNinstall/Remove the currently installed mysql before you install the version you are trying to install.